# Is it possible to stop a loop from another function in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops

I want a program that starts with the main menu that branches off to different functions. At the end of each function I want the user to be asked 'Do you want to go back to the main menu?' if the user says no I want the program to terminate by stopping the main loop (I don't want to use sys.exit() or anything similar).
Example code:

```
#Issue is almost at the bottom
#Feel free to comment on the rest of the code as well,
#Always looking to improve
def main():
    loop = True
    while loop:
        print('''MENU CHOICE''')
        print('''1: go here''')
        print('''2: go there''')
        print('''3: You get the point''')
        print('''0: Terminate program''')
        print()

        try:
            answer = int(input('''I want to go to program: '''))
        except:
            print('''Not a valid menu choice, please try again''')
            print()

        if answer != 1 and answer != 2 and answer != 3 and answer != 0:
            print('''Not a valid menu choice, please try again''')
            print()
        elif answer == 1:
            program1()
        elif answer == 2:
            program2()
        elif answer == 3:
            program3()
        else:
            loop = False

def program1():
    print('''This is program 1''')
    itdontwork = input('''Do you want to go back to the menu? Y/N''')

    if itdontwork == 'Y' or itdontwork == 'y':
        print()
    else:
        print('''SHUTTING DOWN''')
        loop = False #Here is the issue

#The rest of the programs would be the same

main()
```

Comment: You could just `return True` if they want to go back and `return False` if they don't, and then in the main loop set the value of `loop` to whatever is returned by the function that was just called. Your main loop will return to the `while loop` statement, see that `loop == False`, and terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to make your variable loop global

```
loop = True
def main():
    global loop
    while loop:
        print('''MENU CHOICE''')
        print('''1: go here''')
        print('''2: go there''')
        print('''3: You get the point''')
        print('''0: Terminate program''')
        print()

        try:
            answer = int(input('''I want to go to program: '''))
        except:
            print('''Not a valid menu choice, please try again''')
            print()

        if answer != 1 and answer != 2 and answer != 3 and answer != 0:
            print('''Not a valid menu choice, please try again''')
            print()
        elif answer == 1:
            program1()
        elif answer == 2:
            program2()
        elif answer == 3:
            program3()
        else:
            loop = False

def program1():
    global loop
    print('''This is program 1''')
    itdontwork = input('''Do you want to go back to the menu? Y/N''')

    if itdontwork == 'Y' or itdontwork == 'y':
        print()
    else:
        print('''SHUTTING DOWN''')
        loop = False #Here is the issue

#The rest of the programs would be the same

main()
```

Global will allow you to have the same w/r variable everywhere. Without global all variables a local.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to change a variable that was defined outside the scope of the `program1` function. `loop` was defined inside `main` therefore only `main` can access it. There are several ways to fix this, you could declare `loop` outside (make it a global) or just make your `program1` return a boolean to the caller function, e.g.:

```
def main():
    loop = True
    while loop:
        loop = program1()

def program1():
    itdontwork = input('''Do you want to go back to the menu? Y/N''')
    if itdontwork == 'Y' or itdontwork == 'y':
        print()
    else:
        print('''SHUTTING DOWN''')
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to try to do is have the different programs return a value.

The problem is that the functions get executed but return nothing. Your main function returns nothing; therefore the loop variable can never be updated to break the loop.

```
#Issue is almost at the bottom
#Feel free to comment on the rest of the code as well,
#Always looking to improve
def main():
    loop = True
    while loop:
        print('''MENU CHOICE''')
        print('''1: go here''')
        print('''2: go there''')
        print('''3: You get the point''')
        print('''0: Terminate program''')
        print()

        try:
            answer = int(input('''I want to go to program: '''))
        except:
            print('''Not a valid menu choice, please try again''')
            print()

        if answer != 1 and answer != 2 and answer != 3 and answer != 0:
            print('''Not a valid menu choice, please try again''')
            print()
        elif answer == 1:
            return program1() # Return the output of this function
        elif answer == 2:
            return program2() # Return the output of this function
        elif answer == 3:
            return program3() # Return the output of this function
        else:
            loop = False

def program1():
    print('''This is program 1''')
    itdontwork = input('''Do you want to go back to the menu? Y/N''')

    if itdontwork == 'Y' or itdontwork == 'y':
        print()
    else:
        print('''SHUTTING DOWN''')
        return False # Return the output of this function

#The rest of the programs would be the same

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
...
        elif answer == 1:
            loop = program1()
        elif answer == 2:
            loop = program2()
        elif answer == 3:
            loop = program3()
        else:
            loop = False

def program1():
    print('''This is program 1''')
    itdontwork = input('''Do you want to go back to the menu? Y/N''')

    if itdontwork == 'Y' or itdontwork == 'y':
        print()
        return 1 # back to menu...
    else:
        print('''SHUTTING DOWN''')
        return 0
```

This will get the data you need from the called functions to the loop as you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can `raise ValueError('Words and stuff')` and then trap on it.

```
if answer != 1 and answer != 2 and answer != 3 and answer != 0:
    print('''Not a valid menu choice, please try again''')
    print()
elif answer == 1:
    try:
        program1()
    except ValueError:
        break
elif answer == 2:
    try:
        program2()
    except ValueError:
        break
elif answer == 3:
    try:
        program3()
    except ValueError:
        break
else:
    loop = False


def program1():
    print('''This is program 1''')
    itdontwork = input('''Do you want to go back to the menu? Y/N''')

    if itdontwork == 'Y' or itdontwork == 'y':
        print()
    else:
        print('''SHUTTING DOWN''')
        # loop = False #Here is the issue
        raise ValueError('BOOM SHAKA LAKA!')
```